# Extending container getting error on templates

Tags: magento2, extend, containers

after extending product main info container I do not see any add to cart form in product view. Checking the logs I see

```
main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'product/view/addtocart.phtml' in module: 'MY_Custom' block's name: 'product.info.addtocart' []
```

the way as I extended in my theme

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <container name="product.container" as="productContainer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-container" before="-">
            <block class="MY\Custom\Block\Info" name="custom.info" template="MY_Custom::info.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Special Product</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="product.info.addtocart" destination="product.info.main" />
    <move element="product.info.main" destination="product.container" />
    <move element="custom.info" destination="product.info.main" />
    <move element="product.info.media" destination="product.container" after="product.info.main" />
```

Actually I would like to keep all other references I do not want to override

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set ***product.info.addtocart*** block template file  by below code:

```
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: thanks is working but instead I added the xml to custom module which extends in this case the base module